# multiple case condtion for multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Table1

```
id1_a   id2_a   id3_a
1       -1       3
```

Table2

```
id1_b   id2_b   id3_b
4         6       5
```

All id columns are of `integer` type.

Desired ouput with single key column

```
key 
1/-1/3      
4/6/5
```

case statement needed for key column formed by joining 2 tables

Comment: CASE statement is for condition checking, what are your conditions?

Comment: Basically my key values are spread across tables and when I combine to form a key I need to combine the columns from multiple tables here 1/-1/3 as 1 key coumn entry similarly 4/6/5 is another entry after combining columns. Hence select statement with case probably is needed to form key column value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,id1_a)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id2_a)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id3_a) AS [KEY]
FROM table1
UNION
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,id1_b)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id2_b)+'/'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,id3_b)
FROM table2
```